# TextFx add on isnt showing up

Tags: 3d-view, add-on

I've installed TextFx add on but it doesn't show up. It says I need to upgrade but I'm using 2.93. I even downloaded a older version on Blender 2.8 just to see if I could get to work and it says the same thing. When I hit N it only shows Item Tool View. I would really like to use this add on.[image]

Comment: The message means that the actual *add-on* needs to be updated to work with Blender 2.8+. Suggest ask the author of the add-on to update it... there is nothing we can do.

Comment: No, its the same problem but the answer didn't work. For some reason the add on isn't working. Saying update required.

Comment: I found the problem, I found another version that works. I guess I had a old version of it.